# Explain more about date range filter is better than function YEAR() and DATE()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reading book *T-SQL fundamental - 3rd edition*, page 98 by Itzik Ben-Gan.

Solution 1:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid 
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2015 AND MONTH(orderdate) = 6;
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid 
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE orderdate >= '20150106' AND orderdate <= '20150130';
```

Author said:

> Apply manipulation to the filtered column, in most case SQL Server
>   can't use an index efficiently. Therefore, I advice using a range
>   filter instead.

Please explain for me. Why date range filter is better than function `YEAR()` and `DATE()`?

Comment: The author is pretty specific on the reason, what about that is it you want explanation on or is unclear?

Comment: yes, please explain more, I don't understand the author's comment.

Comment: This might be related to your query. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/

Comment: Are you not famiilar with what an `INDEX` is then? As I asked, what about said statement don't you understand?

Comment: @Larnu I know about *index* a column in database for looking up faster. However, talk about index in this context, make me not undertand.

Comment: I suggest you lean about [sargable expressions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827764/Sargable-query-in-SQL-server) - which has examples of what that means (including one involving dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a query such as:

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid 
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE . . .
```

The database engine essentially has two ways to process the query.  One method is to cycle through all the rows in `Orders` and check to see if each row matches the condition.

The second method -- if possible -- is to use an index to determine the specific rows that need to be fetched.  In general, this is much faster, because the database engine only needs to read the rows that match the condition.

The issue is that this condition:

```
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2015 AND MONTH(orderdate) = 6
```

cannot use the index.  Actually, this is a statement about *practice* not *theory*.  Theoretically, the engine could figure out that `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` are non-decreasing functions and make use of the index.  No database does that.  Instead, the database just says:  "Oh, there is a function call.  I can't use the index."

For this condition:

```
WHERE orderdate >= '20150106' AND orderdate <= '20150130'
```

The database *can* make use of an index.  It can find the first row in the index that matches `orderdate >= '20150106'`.  It can then scan the index for the subsequent rows up to (and including) `'20150130'`.  In general, the database will decide that this is faster.

But, at the very least, eliminating the function calls gives the optimizer the opportunity to use an index for the condition.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is is that you don't understand here, as although the statement is short, it's very specific.

When you use functions on a column, like `YEAR` and `MONTH`, the data engine cannot make use of the indexes. Indexes help the data engine find the rows you want; just like the index in a book. If you can't use an index there is only one way of finding the information you want, reading the **entirety** of the data. Again, just like with a book, reading everything is much slower than going to the right pages/row with the information you need on them.

Using proper date logic, by not applying functions to the columns, means that the data engine can use any relevant indexes you have on the table, and so it can find the information asked for quicker and more efficiently.

This doesn't just apply to dates though. Something like `ISNULL(MyColumn,@MyVariable) = @MyVariable` or `CONVERT(int,NumericalColumn) = 1` is just "as bad". There are *very* few functions that can be applied to a column in the `WHERE` that maintain SARGability, and even then that doesn't mean they should be used.

---

To put some perspective on this, imagine you are given a phone book. The phone book has an index of surnames, and people in the phone book at listed in Surname, FirstName order.

Imagine being asked to find all the people in the book with the surname "Smith". You flick the the index, find the page number Smith starts on, and the write them all down. In terms of a SQL query, this would be `WHERE Surname = 'Smith'`

Now imagine you are asked to find all the people with the surname Smith or beings with Smith. Again, you'd flick the index, find all the names that start with Smith (which would all be adjacent in the index), note the page numbers, then go to those pages and write them down. In terms of a SQL query, this would be `WHERE Surname LIKE 'Smith%'`

Now, what if the last statement was `WHERE LEFT(Surname,5) = 'Smith'`. This *seems* identical however the question is different. This would be translated in words, to something more like "Take the first 5 characters of every surname. Now check if they have the value 'Smith' and write them down along with the Firstname and Phone Number for that person." Notice that you need to check *every* person's surname first, then only write down the ones you want.

For something like `MONTH` this problem is more severe. It would be like giving you said same phone book and asking "Provide a list of all people in the phone book who's first name is 'Jane'". With an index only on the Surname, you have no choice but to look at **every** person in the phone book.

*Note, indexes aren't quite as simple as this in databases. An (nonclustered) index on `Surname` alone would actually be useless to the RDBMS if you wanted someone's First Name and phone number. At a minimum the `FirstName` and `PhoneNumber` columns would need to be `INCLUDED` in the index too.*